# SERENITY_FORK_NUMBER Serenity-BDD Cucumber Maven RestAssured

Tags: maven, cucumber, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <slf4jVersion>1.7.25</slf4jVersion>
    <serenity.version>1.9.19</serenity.version>
    <serenity.maven.version>2.0.9</serenity.maven.version>
    <serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.19</serenity.cucumber.version>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <tags></tags>
    <parallel.tests>4</parallel.tests>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.*</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.20</version>
      <configuration>
        <forkCount>3</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*Test.java</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>integration-test</goal>
            <goal>verify</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*.*</include>
          </includes>
          <argLine>-Duser.language=en</argLine>
          <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
          <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
          <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
          <useFile>false</useFile>
          <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <tags>${tags}</tags>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>serenity-reports</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>aggregate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.shazam</groupId>
      <artifactId>shazamcrest</artifactId>
      <version>0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-rest-assured -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
      <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.javacrumbs.json-unit</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-unit</artifactId>
      <version>1.28.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
      <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
          <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
      <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
      <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
      <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
      <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
      <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
      <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-picocontainer -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
      <artifactId>serenity-picocontainer</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
      <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my POM. I have setup RestAssured/Cucumber/Maven/ framework. I wanted to use serenityBDD in my framework. For reporting purpose. So I am runnning my cukestest like below

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
```

When I run the tests I get the error below

```
    [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.965 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.whitbread.RunCukesTest
[ERROR] com.whitbread.RunCukesTest  Time elapsed: 0.964 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SERENITY_FORK_NUMBER
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   JUnit4Provider.invoke:159->executeTestSet:236->executeWithRerun:272->execute:363 » NoSuchField
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO]
```

I have restassured/cucumber/maven project.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a version mismatch. Your serenity-cucumber 1.9.19 depends on serenity-core 2.0.8 minimum. See: [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber/1.9.19)
You override serenity-core 2.0.8 with 1.9.19. Solution: don't depend on serenity-core as it comes with serenity-cucumber.

Same for selenium-java 3.9.1 which needs guava 23.6-jre instead of 23. And gson 2.8.2 instead of 2.8.0

Extra: You don't need to depend on xml-apis as it comes with serenity-picocontainer. And hamcrest-library brings hamcrest-core.

Last notes: I did not check everything. And the future of com.jayway.restassured is in io.rest-assured. Your pom seems to belong to a new project so you should probably change your imports from jayway to io soon.

Comment: You're welcome Satya. And if it helped you, you could help others be giving my answer a +1